# Copy an outlook email to a folder or read the email via javamail? 

Tags: java, email, outlook

We are handling many emails from our clients. Each email that has a subject line with a case number is uploaded to our CRM. Currently we have our analyst doing this process, ie., every email he gets or sends he copy the email to the desktop and later upload that file to the relevant case.

This is very tedious and time consuming. My Design question here is this:

Option 1: read the email via java mail and if the subject line has a case number - simply get the content and the attachments and upload the email to the crm.

Or

Option 2: copy the outlook email to the desktop and then upload the email **as a file** to the crm.

I'm not sure but it looks that option 2 is better because everything in the email (attachments, docs, diagram, photos) will be uploaded and when the analysis will refer to the caseid he will be able to see the email 'as is' (as if it's from outlook).

First option save me the hessle to work with outlook but I'm afraid the email will be only text (not sure if there's a way to upload the entire email as if it's an outlook file)

Thanks for any pointers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first option of directly connecting to the mailserver is actually pretty straightforward.

We do something pretty similar by logging in to our Exchange server using JavaMail: a Java application connects to Exchange on a regular basis and processes any mail it finds. Once it has processed an email, it moves it to another folder so it doesn't get processed again.

I don't quite understand how your second option would work, but connecting up Java code to Outlook sounds difficult more difficult to me.

Here's an outline of how to use JavaMail to process emails on an Exchange server. It should work for any mailserver that supports IMAP:

```
public void processMailExample() {
   Store store = session.getStore(new javax.mail.URLName("imap://user:pass@mailserver..."));
   store.connect();
   Folder inputFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
   Folder outputFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX/Processed");

   inputFolder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

   Message[] messages = inputFolder.getMessages();
   for (Message message : messages) {

       // Process message here

       moveMessage(message, outputFolder);
   }
}

public void moveMessage(Message m, Folder to) throws MessagingException
{
    m.getFolder().copyMessages(new Message[] {m}, to);
    m.setFlag(Flag.DELETED, true);
    m.getFolder().expunge();
}
```

If a particular email has attachments then it will be an instance of `javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage` rather than just `Message`. The `MimeMessage` class gives you full access to all attachments, HTML, etc so you should be able to access everything you need to upload into your CRM system.