# copy email only from outlook to CRM 2011

Tags: email, outlook, integration, dynamics-crm-2011, jakarta-mail

I am having issue with one of the solution I am working for Customer Services department. We get customer enquiries in the form of call or emails. I have setup a dilog process that captures all the details it need for raising a new case.

Issue starts when we want to attaching email conversation to that case. The only solution that I can think of is to save email and attach it to the case. But some times we have to send out 5-6 or even 10 emails to customer before the case is closed. This means that every time an email is sent, it has to be attached to the case. (takes up extra space on server too). This is not a very practicle solution as you will agree.

We don't want to use Outlook integration option either because that is what they are using at the moment and is creating more issues then solving them. I have searched here and found some similar topic that suggest to use Jama Mail ([Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10875082/copy-an-outlook-email-to-a-folder-or-read-the-email-via-javamail) but how that will attach email to a particular contact in CRM, I am not sure.

Is there any way to just attache email for the first time and from that point it automatically capture all conversations? I will would be very grateful if you can help me out here.

Answer (score 2):

Difficult to answer since you say "excluding the one simple and correct way of doing this using the very capable and customisable Outlook client"... (or words to that effect).

The right way to do this using the Outlook client would be to Set Regarding on the first email in the chain (or indeed take an inbound email and Convert to Case, which will also set regarding on the email to the new Case).

Smart Matching combined with Outlook option to "automatically track emails in response to CRM email" should do the trick.

Using email tracking tokens will make this more reliable, if you "Set Regarding" an email before you send it (eg first response to customer after logging Case) then it gets a token in the subject line which helps guarantee the uniqueness of the conversation so future emails are tracked automatically and regarding the correct Case.

Comment: thanks guys for kind help. I am going on to the route or Outlook set regarding. As for them losing the connection (Outlook to CRM) I will rather spend time in find the cause for that connection error.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to attach the first email and have it automatically attach all further messages in that conversation.  Someone is going to have to write the software to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It will save me time looking around for the solution. For now though, I will just use 'Set Regarding' function from Outlook and attach email to cases. Something we didn't wanted but it either that or save and attach eh?